# Using wget to finish a downloaing

Tags: wget

I was downloading a big file but without wget tool, the good news is that the link of the file has the following form:

https://link.com/file.zip

Sadly, the downloaing was broken, so now I want to keep downloading this file but without starting from 0%. When I was downloading the file, It saved as "file.zip" but when wget tool with the `-c` command in order to keep downloading the same file, it inmediately saved as "another-name.zip" I know I can use the `-o` command in order to save the file with name I want but I have not idea what commads should I use in order to restart the downloading where it stayed with the file.zip name.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, quite correctly, wget -c is for continuing downloading a file.

However, for the -c to work, the server has to support HTTP range requests/partial downloads.

Usually, they are supported, however if not, the download will have to start again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The option you're looking for is `-O`:

> ```
> -O file    --output-document=file
>    The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
>    will be concatenated together and written to file.
> ```

So, `wget -cO local_file http://example.com/remote_file` (provided, of course, that the remote server supports ranges)

> I know I can use the `-o` command in order to save the file with name

No, the smaller case `-o file` option will save to `file` the messages that `wget` usually prints to standard error, not the data it's fetching from the remote server.